# Control the Volume of the sound not the computer mixer, having the data C#

Tags: c#, volume, audio, winmm

I have managed to capture the sound from the microphone and output it to the speaker
using many ways `NAudio` and the `Winmm.dll` but the problem is that the sound's volume is low unless i get so close to the microphone then its loud !!
i have the data like this:

```
byte[] indata;
byte[] outdata;
Stream fiFoStream;
```

is there is any way that i can turn the volume up using the data bytes or i need other resources. knowing that i tried using the `winmm.dll` functions

```
string mmdll = "winmm.dll";
[DllImport(mmdll)]
public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hWaveOut, int dwVolume);
[DllImport(mmdll)]
public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hWaveOut, out int dwVolume);
```

and i didn't get the result needed, any help is appreciated :) Yaser.

Comment: Do a search on "audio compression" to learn what is involved in making sound louder.

Comment: I might be wrong but maybe your microphone audio capture level is low. You can check the level opening the volume mixer. If that's the case and input audio level is low, you can edit it programmatically via `mixerSetControlDetails`. Good luck